# Was the radio intro in "Protect Ya Neck" real or created for the song?

Tags: lyrics

The probably most famous song of the [*Wu-Tang Clan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu-Tang_Clan) [*"Protect Ya Neck"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protect_Ya_Neck) from the album [*Enter the Wu-Tang (36 Chambers)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_the_Wu-Tang_(36_Chambers)) starts with this radio talk:

> **Caller:** "So whassup man?"
>
> **DJ:** "Coolin' man"
>
> **C:** "Chillin' chilin'? Yo, you know I had to call, you know why right?"
>
> **DJ:** "Why?"
>
> **C:** "Because, yo, I never ever call and ask you to play somethin' right?"
>
> **DJ:** "Yeah"
>
> **C:** "You know what I wanna hear, right?"
>
> **DJ:** "Whatchu wanna hear?"
>
> **C:** "I wanna hear that Wu-Tang joint"
>
> **DJ:** "Wu-Tang again?"
>
> **C:** "Ahh yea, again and again"

**Did this actually happen on a real radio show (if so, which one?) or was it made up for the song (who plays the roles)?**

As a bonus you can also answer *why* there's a radio intro in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Wikipedia article of this song it says that it is from an interview on a radio station:

> The person who rings into a radio station at the start of the song was from an interview Wu did. Wu did the interview on a radio station ("Virginia or Maryland, WPGC, I think" Inspectah Deck says), different segments of the same interview are placed at different parts of the album.

Howsoever, in the annotations of the lyrics on [Genius](http://genius.com/2681366/Wu-tang-clan-protect-ya-neck/Intro-caller-so-whassup-man-dj-coolin-man-c-chillin-chilin-yo-you-know-i-had-to-call-you-why-right-dj-why-c-because-you-i-never-ever-call-and-ask-you-to-play-somethin-right-dj-yeah-c-you-know-what-i-wanna-hear-right-dj-whatchu-wanna-hear-c-i-wanna-hear-that-wu-tang-joint-dj-wu-tang-again-c-ahh-yea-again-and-again) it says:

> The intro is taken from an exchange between a listener who called in on a [City College](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_College_of_New_York) radio station

In the same annotation it's also stated *why*:

> RZA included this intro on this song **to demonstrate Wu-Tang’s growing popularity** — “Protect Ya Neck” was Wu’s debut single which sold 10,000 copies underground, leading to the group’s signing with [Loud Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loud_Records).

So it seems to be a real dialogue that was not scripted but it's unclear where it originated from.